# What are jQuery and Bootstrap version requirements for Bootstrap Table?

Tags: bootstrap-table

The only versions I find in code samples on the Bootstrap Table site use jQuery 1.x.  Will 2.x or 3.x work?  What about Bootstrap v4?

Answer (score 8):

Bootstrap and required jquery version:

```
[jQuery 1.7.1 > bootstrap 2.0.3]
[jQuery 1.9.1 > bootstrap 2.3.0|2.3.2]
[jQuery 1.9.1 > bootstrap 3.0.0-rc1]
[jQuery 1.10.2 > bootstrap 3.0.0]
[jQuery 1.11.2 > bootstrap 3.3.4]
[jQuery 1.12.4 > bootstrap 3.3.7]
[jQuery 1.11.3 > bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha]

[jQuery 2.2.4 > bootstrap 3.3.6]
[jQuery 3.2.1 > bootstrap 3.3.7]

[jQuery 3.1.1 > bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha6
```

Bootstrap 3 includes jQuery as dependency, here's the bower.json of Bootstrap
Regard.

Answer (score 4):

As `bootstrap-table` currently lists a dependency and acts as an extension of `"twitter/bootstrap": ">=2.3.0"`, `bootstrap-table` technically is forced to follow the same dependency rules as the prerequisites that Bootstrap uses.

The general concept is to use a package manager to require the desired version of Bootstrap, followed by `bootstrap-table`.

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3",
    "bootstrap-table": ">= 1.0"
}
```

The package manager would then install a compatible version of `bootstrap-table` for the desired version of Bootstrap.

Requiring only `bootstrap-table` would otherwise always install the latest version of Bootstrap and its prerequisites.

---

To determine the Bootstrap prerequisites, as per the [getting started section](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included) on the Bootstrap website.

> jQuery required Please note that all JavaScript plugins require jQuery
>   to be included, as shown in the starter template. Consult our
>   bower.json to see which versions of jQuery are supported.

Looking at the bower dependencies for Bootstrap version `3.3.7`.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/bower.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "1.9.1 - 3"
}
```

Meaning Bootstrap 3.3.7 will work with jQuery 1.9.1 through 3.x

Previous versions of Bootstrap (3.0 to 3.3.5) listed a dependency of `jQuery >= 1.9.1`, meaning it was expected to work with any version of jQuery greater than or equal to version 1.9.1.

Looking at the bower dependencies for Bootstrap version `4.0.0`.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.0.0-alpha.2/bower.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "1.9.1 - 2"
}
```

Meaning Bootstrap 4 requires jQuery 1.9.1 through 2.x, which generally means something will break with jQuery 3.x, though I have not confirmed this.

Comment: This question is about the product Bootstrap Table (http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) , not Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: Seeing as it is an extension of `"twitter/bootstrap": ">=2.3.0"` it should technically follow the same dependency rules, as its prerequisite version. Though bootstrap table lists `"dependencies": {
    "jquery": ">=1.7"
  },` where Bootstrap 2.3.x lists `"dependencies": {
    "jquery": ">=1.8.0 <2.1.0"
  }`